# Does glDrawElements result in fewer vertex shaders to run compared to glDrawArrays?

Tags: opengl

I know that glDrawArrays will run the vertex shader as many times as the *count* parameter is specified, even if the *count* exceeds the number of vertices currently bound in the VAO. But what about glDrawElements? Does it run the vertex shader for each vertex or for each index (resulting in duplication)?

Comment: "*even if the count exceeds the number of vertices currently bound in the VAO*" That would yield undefined behavior (or an OpenGL error; I forget which), since the "number of vertices" in the various buffers is based on the *sizes* of those buffers. So you would be reading from memory outside of the buffers.